# Conditional GroupBy with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this source that I get  from a procedure that I use in my method where I use linq. I have to group the source by ProfileParent, then by ProfileSubParent and ProfileName are the nodes. The problem I have is that not all ProfileNames have a ProfileSubParent and when that happens I don't want them to be grouped I just want them to stand on their own. So from a 3 level tree I want a 2 level tree when I don't have a ProfileSubParent

`Id ProfileName ProfileParent   ProfileSubParent    Active
1   Node 1              Menu    Sub menu 1             1

2   Node 2              Menu    Sub menu 1             1
3   Node 3              Menu    -                      1
4   Node 4              Menu    -                      1`

The return I want to get from the method where i use linq is :

```
[{
    "label":"Menu",
    "selected":false,
    "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
    "children":[  
    {  
        "label":"Sub menu 1",
        "selected":false,
        "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
        "children":[  
        {  
            "Id":1,
            "ProfileName":"Node 1",
            "ProfileDescription":"Node 1",
            "ProfileLongDescription":"Node 1",
            "Active":false,
            "label":"Node 1",
            "selected":false
        },
        {  
            "Id":2,
            "ProfileName":"Node 2",
            "ProfileDescription":"Node 2",
            "ProfileLongDescription":"Node 2",
            "Active":false,
            "label":"Node 2",
            "selected":false
        }
    ]
    },
    {
        "label":"Node 3",
        "selected":false,
        "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
        "children":[]
    },
    {
        "label":"Node 4",
        "selected":false,
        "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
        "children":[]
    }]
}]
```

---

This is the code I have but the return I get from it is not what I want.

```
 result.GroupBy(gr => new { gr.ProfileParent })
                      .Select(grupet =>  new ProfileRightsParent
                      {
                          label = grupet.Key.ProfileParent,
                          selected = grupet.Count() == grupet.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().Count() ? true : false,
                          __ivhTreeviewIndeterminate = (grupet.Count() != grupet.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().Count() && grupet.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().Count() != 0) ? true : false,
                          children = grupet.GroupBy(sub => new { sub.ProfileSubParent }).Select
                                      (sub => new ProfileRightsSubParent
                                      {
                                          label = sub.Key.ProfileSubParent,
                                          selected = sub.Count() == sub.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().Count() ? true : false,
                                          __ivhTreeviewIndeterminate = (sub.Count() != sub.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().Count() && sub.Where(x => x.Active == true).ToList().Count() != 0) ? true : false,
                                          children = sub.Select(details => new ProfileLine()
                                          {
                                              Id = details.Id,
                                              ProfileName = details.ProfileName,
                                              ProfileDescription = details.ProfileDescription,
                                              ProfileLongDescription = details.ProfileLongDescription,
                                              Active = details.Active,
                                              selected = details.Active,
                                              label = details.ProfileDescription
                                          }).ToList()

                                      }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();
```

---

The return I get is:

```
[{  
    "label":"Menu",
    "selected":false,
    "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
    "children":[  
    {  
        "label":"Sub menu 1",
        "selected":false,
        "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
        "children":[  
        {  
            "Id":1,
            "ProfileName":"Node 1",
            "ProfileDescription":"Node 1",
            "ProfileLongDescription":"Node 1",
            "Active":false,
            "label":"Node 1",
            "selected":false
        },
        {  
            "Id":2,
            "ProfileName":"Node 2",
            "ProfileDescription":"Node 2",
            "ProfileLongDescription":"Node 2",
            "Active":false,
            "label":"Node 2",
            "selected":false
        }]
    },
    {  
        "label":" ",
        "selected":false,
        "__ivhTreeviewIndeterminate":false,
        "children":[  
        {  
            "Id":1,
            "ProfileName":"Node 3",
            "ProfileDescription":"Node 3",
            "ProfileLongDescription":"Node 3",
            "Active":false,
            "label":"Node 3",
            "selected":false
        },
        {  
            "Id":2,
            "ProfileName":"Node 4",
            "ProfileDescription":"Node 4",
            "ProfileLongDescription":"Node 4",
            "Active":false,
            "label":"Node 4",
            "selected":false
        }]
    },]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `Where()` before doing a `GroupBy` to avoid taking null elements.
The simplest method I have found is to add the elements with an `AddRange` after the global `GroupBy`.
I also simplified some elements of your Linq with the `All` and`Any` methods

```
var res = result.GroupBy(gr => gr.ProfileParent)
         .Select(grupet => new ProfileRightsParent
         {
             label = grupet.Key,
             selected = grupet.All(x => x.Active),
             __ivhTreeviewIndeterminate = !grupet.All(x => x.Active) && grupet.Any(x => x.Active),
             children = grupet.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProfileSubParent)).GroupBy(sub => sub.ProfileSubParent).Select
                         (sub => new ProfileRightsSubParent
                         {
                             label = sub.Key,
                             selected = sub.All(x => x.Active),
                             __ivhTreeviewIndeterminate = !sub.All(x => x.Active) && sub.Any(x => x.Active),
                             children = sub.Select(details => new ProfileLine()
                             {
                                 Id = details.Id,
                                 ProfileName = details.ProfileName,
                                 ProfileDescription = details.ProfileDescription,
                                 ProfileLongDescription = details.ProfileLongDescription,
                                 Active = details.Active,
                                 selected = details.Active,
                                 label = details.ProfileDescription
                             }).ToList()
                         }).ToList()
         }).ToList();

res.AddRange(result
    .Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProfileSubParent))
    .Select(detail => new ProfileRightsParent
    {
        label = detail.ProfileName,
        selected = false,
        __ivhTreeviewIndeterminate = false
    }));
```

Comment: I had tried to use Where() before grouping, but what it does is ignoring the nodes completely.

Comment: @Whatives Yes, that's why you have to add an AddRange to take these null lines

Comment: Yea but still it wasn't doing what I wanted.
I kind of fixed the issue by removing Where and adding this condition to the groupby
`grupet.GroupBy(sub => string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub.ProfileSubParent) ? sub.ProfileName  : sub.ProfileSubParent)`